# Não estou conseguindo adicionar uma mesma variável numa pilha e desenhá-la

Tags: c++, sfml

Estou tentando fazer um programa que faça uma pilha de objetos utilizando a lib *stack* e logo em seguida desenhar o que estiver no topo, para fazer alguns testes eu estava fazendo o seguinte:

```
int main() {

    RenderWindow wind(VideoMode(VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width, VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height), "titulo");

    Tile a = Tile(Vector2f(100,100), "txr_Wall.jpg", true);
    stack<Tile> f;
    f.push(a);
    a = Tile(Vector2f(100, 100), "txr_Grass.jpg", true);
    f.push(a);

    while (wind.isOpen()) {

        wind.clear(Color::Red);

        wind.draw(f.top().getSprite());

        wind.display();

    }
```

Assim do jeito que está o código dá *crash*, mas assim que eu crio outro objeto do tipo `Tile` e dou push para a pilha funciona normalmente. Alguém pode me explicar o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Os atributos da classe `Tile` são todos ponteiros que são inicializados com `new`. Não sei se ajuda, mas estou trabalhando com SFML.

Fiz um teste e deu certo. Criei um novo `Tile b` (inicializado diferente), e fiz `a = b` e dei `push` em `a` novamente e funcionou. Alguém consegue explicar?

Comment: Sem sabermos a definição de `Tile`, é impossível dar alguma ajuda.

Comment: Assim que possível colocarei a definição.